# Introductory reading on vine copulas

Tags: references, copula, vine-copula

I am looking for a gentle introduction into vine copulas and R-vines in particular.
(There is a [related thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37951) for copulas in general, but the answers there do not seem to contain an introduction into vine copulas.)

Answer (score 2):

- Textbook: Czado ["Analyzing Dependent Data with Vine Copulas: A Practical Guide With R"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030137847) (2019). R-vines are presented in chapters 5-9.
- Slides: Kramer & Schepsmeier ["Introduction to vine copulas"](https://www.groups.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00ccg/statistics/veranstaltungen/Vines.pdf) (2011)
- Slides: Haff ["How To Select A Good Vine"](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/research/projects/focustat/workshops%20and%20conference/workshop-2016/vineselection.pdf) (2016)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vine_copula): quite detailed.